Row permutations of a column-block-diagonal adjacency matrix
Suppose I have an $n\times m$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ which has a "column-block-diagonal" form in the sense that it consists of $m$ column-blocks of unit vectors, such that:
$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{1}_{n_1} & \mathbf{0}_{n_1} & \mathbf{0}_{n_1} & ... \mathbf{0}_{n_1} \\ \mathbf{0}_{n_2} & \mathbf{1}_{n_2} & \mathbf{0}_{n_2} & ... \mathbf{0}_{n_2} \\
... \\ \mathbf{0}_{n_k} & \mathbf{0}_{n_k} & \mathbf{0}_{n_k} & ... \mathbf{1}_{n_m}\end{bmatrix},$$
where $\mathbf{1}_{n_i}$ and $\mathbf{0}_{n_i}$ denote unit and zero vectors of length ${n_i} \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}$ respectively, and with $n = \sum_{i=1}^m n_i \ge m$.
A particular instance of a $\mathbf{A}$ can be specified by $(n_1, \ldots, n_m)$.
In my context, this matrix represents a possible adjacency matrix of a (small portion of a) graph. For example, for $n = 3$, $m = 2$, and $(n_1, n_2) = (1, 2)$, it represents the graph:

I'm interested the set of unique row permutations of the general $(n_1, \ldots, n_m)$ matrix. For instance, in the above example, row permutations can generate two additional variants:

Many of the row-permutations, however, result in identical matrices, since permutations of rows within a block doesn't change the matrix. In the above $(n_1, n_2) = (1, 2)$ example, the permutations $(123)$ & $(132)$, $(213)$ & $(312)$, and $(321)$ & $(231)$ give the same matrix.
Considering this, the total count of row permutations that produce unique matrices (or, equivalently, the cardinality of the set of row permutations of a $(n_1, \ldots, n_m)$ matrix) is:
$$ 
\text{unique permutations} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_m!} = \frac{\big(\sum_{i=1}^m n_i)!}{\prod_{i=1}^m n_i!}
= \begin{pmatrix} n \\ n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_m\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the last expression is the multinomial coefficient.
My questions are:

Is this set of permutations known by any name or concept?
Is the $(n_1, \ldots, n_m)$ matrix known by a name or concept?
How can I generate this set of permutations efficiently?
Is it possible to codify which permutations $(i_{1}i_{2}\ldots i_n)$ of $(12\ldots n)$ are equivalent in the sense that they generate identical matrices?


Okay, I've realized, at least, that this is equivalent to the problem of multiset permutations, as e.g., arising when counting the number of distinct letter-permutations of a word. A remaining unknown for me is how to generate these multiset permutations algorithmically.

For the last one: $\tau$ and $\sigma$ generate the same graph iff $\tau^{-1}\sigma$ is in $\times_i S_{n_i}$

In answer to my own questions:


Is this set of permutations known by any name or concept?


They are the multiset permutations of the multiset $\{n_1\cdot 1, n_2 \cdot 2, \ldots, n_m \cdot m\}$.


Is the $(n_1,\ldots,n_m)$ matrix known by a name or concept?


Not so far as I've been able to gather. It's a variant of block-diagonal matrices, with columns for blocks.


How can I generate this set of permutations efficiently.


The permutations of multisets - or sequences with repeated elements - are described in Algorithm L of the Donald Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4A.
I've uploaded an implementation, adapted from Julia's Combinatorics.jl multiset_permutations, on gist: https://gist.github.com/thchr/00a99939100c03a19e0b6b689908ab3b. This returns the indices of the permutations of $\{n_1\cdot 1, n_2 \cdot 2, \ldots, n_m \cdot m\} = \{1, \ldots_{n_1}, 1, 2, \ldots_{n_2}, 2, \ldots, m, \ldots_{n_m}, m\}$, rather than the permutations themselves.


Is it possible to codify which permutations $(i_1i_2…i_n)$
of $(12\ldots n)$  are equivalent in the sense that they generate identical matrices?


See comment by @Exodd for one example of a simple relation.
